# How to extract the token from SNS Subscribe and use it in confirmSubscription method?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

**Usecase**

I want to subscribe email to SNS topic and i need to confirm it programmatically rather than manually clicking at the confirmation link.

**What i had did**

This is usually for confirmation i am using SNS `confirmSubscription` method which will take `token` as a parameter. I can able to achieve the token by calling the SNS `subscribe` method by passing protocol as `email-json`. For this i received the following subscription message at the endpoint.

```
{
  "Type" : "SubscriptionConfirmation",
  "MessageId" : "xxx-9160-49a3-960f-xx",
  "Token" : "2336412f37fb687adfaf",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xx-xx",
  "Message" : "You have chosen to subscribe to the topic arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xx-xx.\nTo confirm the subscription, visit the SubscribeURL included in this message.",
  "SubscribeURL" : "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=xx&TopicArn=arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:477530015769:xx-xx&Token=2336412f37fb6872",
  "Timestamp" : "2019-03-21T08:34:26.597Z",
  "SignatureVersion" : "1",
  "Signature" : "bIwq8Q92Yvrn8bBrIDQJ2chc5y/5IPAZPPR4roZ6WfK7kaE0QTbJpqAmHMH0sHL4aoyTrapLwX4e6HaEd6nGny8EAWj5wA2JvFCrO9BFQu",
  "SigningCertURL" : "https://sns.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-xx.pem"
}
```

**What i want**

How can able to extract the `token` value from the above json. This is the below lambda i am using to programmatically confirm the sns subscriber.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var sns = new AWS.SNS();
var snsconfirm= {
  Token: 'xx', /* required */ -->How can i able to retrieve the token value from the endpoint json.
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xxx:xx-xxx', /* required */
  AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe: 'true'
};
var snsparams = {
  Protocol: 'email-json', /* required */
  TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:ap-south-1:xx:xx-xx', /* required */
  Endpoint: 'abc@xyz.com'
};
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement
try {
  const snsrespone = await sns.subscribe(snsparams).promise();
  const confirmsub = await sns.confirmSubscription(snsconfirm).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only programmatically confirm the subscription if you have the token, as you have already found out. This is most likely to make sure you can't subscribe someone unwillingly.

Your only option, assuming you have access to the endpoint, is to setup a filter of some sort that triggers a Lambda that can subscribe off the reply. Possibly by setting an email forward rule in your email to forward to an SES email, that in turn triggers a Lambda that confirms the subscription.